# A problem on the binomial theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Find $x, y$ such that

$$x^3 + c(3,1)x^2 y + C(3,2)xy^2 + y^3 = 64$$

and

$$x^5 - C(5,1)x^4y + C(5,2)x^3y^2 - C(5,3)x^2 y^3 + C(5,4)xy^4 - y^5 = 32.$$

I might solve this problem by inspection, but I'm really after what the question author intended here.  I know $(x + y)^3 = 64$ but $(x + y)^5 \ne 32$.  The author introduced some negative terms, so it's not the binomial expansion and I can't seem to catch on to the idea.

I can see the problem is interested in powers of two.  I know $2^6 = (2^2)^3= 64$ so for the first equation, it seems that $x + y = 4$, but there's an infinite number of solution there.  I don't quite get what the minus signs on the second equation are trying to tell me.  How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In addition to considering binomial expansions of $(x+y)^n$, also consider binomial expansions of $(x-y)^n=\left[x+(-y)\right]^n$.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but I still don't see a relevant connection.  I expanded both.  Omitting the expansion here, I see that $(x + y)^3 = 2^6$ and that $(x - y)^5 = 2^5$.  I kinda see a way out, but I'm sure it's not the intended strategy.  From $(x + y)^3 = 2^6$, we can infer $x + y = 4$ so $x = 4 - y$.  Now I could substitute in the other equation and solve, but it will be a long algebra problem, which is probably not the intention of the author.

Comment: On a second thought, I think I got it.  It must be that $x + y = 4$ for reasons stated in the question and similarly it must be that $x - y = 2$, so we actually have a simple system, not a long algebra problem.  That is, $x = 2 + y$ from the second equation and then applying that on the first equation we get $2 + 2y = 4$ implies $y = 1$, so $x = 3$.   Looks like I got it.  Thanks very much for help!